# What's the difference between CATransaction and CAAnimation?

Tags: ios, core-animation, caanimation, catransaction

maybe duplicated with some question, but I can't find them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CAAnimation is an abstract superclass using CAMediaTiming protocol that can regulate the time,including duration, speed, repetition;also using CAAction protocol, display animation by way of response actions.
2. CATransaction is a derived class of CAAnimation.It can modify properties of multiple layers at same time.
   It has two types of transactions:

   a. **explicit transaction**, Submitting animation by invoking "begin","commit" explicitly,Reset         duration.Transactions can be nesting;

   b. **implicit transaction**. In addition to explicit transaction, any modifications for CALayer properties are implicit transaction, so the transaction will be submitted in the run-loop.

Hope it helps u.

Comment: CATransaction is actually a subclass of NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of good links to understand the difference,

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Transactions.html

http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/core-animation-catransaction-protip/